# What does a ^ with no leading function name mean in mumps

Tags: mumps

I have a piece of mumps code

```
DO ENYA^PRCTQUES
```

and

```
DO ^PRCTQUES
```

I understand what the first one does.  However, I don't know what the 2nd example does. What's it calling?

EDIT - What if the code at the top is all comments?

```
PRCTQUES ; comment
  ;;comment
  ; MOAR comment
  ;
```

So what are we doing here with `DO ^PRCTQUES` ? Just making sure the file exists and is compiled?

Finally what if my file started with the label `ZOOT`?

```
ZOOT
   (code)
  Q
```

then what? Does `DO ^PRCTQUES` invoke the `ZOOT` label because it is at the top? Or do I get an error message?  It looks like bad style of course...

Comment: Laugh at MUMPS all you want, but the `PRCTQUES.m` code above has been running in VA hospitals for 33 years and is going strong.  You can find it on the worldvista site.  #cantarguewithsuccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a routine FOO that looks like this:

```
FOO ; Foo routine
 WRITE "HELLO FOO",!
 QUIT
LABEL ; A line label
 WRITE "HELLO LABEL",!
 QUIT
```

`DO ^FOO` will show the output "HELLO FOO". `DO LABEL^FOO` will show "HELLO LABEL".

So calling a routine without a label (as in `DO ^PRCTQUES`) will execute the routine from the top. Otherwise, with a label `DO ENYA^PRCTQUES` it will run the code starting from the label.

In your edited question, you asked about what happens if you have a routine `PRCTQUES` with a label `ZOOT` at the top. Like this:

```
ZOOT
 WRITE "ZOOT",!
 QUIT
```

In this case, `DO ^PRCTQUES` will write `ZOOT`. Also, `DO ZOOT^PRCTQUES` will also write `ZOOT`. However, because most companies consider it a bad practice that the first label in the routine isn't the routine name, so this is not an example you see in practice.

Comment: Thank you, it is what I expected but I haven't seen it written so clearly.  What does it mean when there's no executable code at the top of the file?  I'll augment my question.

Comment: If there is no executable code on the top of your file, then it continues down until it finds executable code or a quit.

Comment: I updated the answer based on your updated question.

Comment: Also, I just saw that you asked what happens if the file is all comments. Well: nothing happens. `DO ^PRCTQUES` does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

According to Wikipedia:

> All variable names prefixed with the caret character (^) use permanent (instead of RAM) storage, will maintain their values after the application exits, and will be visible to (and modifiable by) other running applications.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS

Comment: So `^PRCTQUES` isn't a file at all, but a persistent variable name, and the actual routine being called is the value of `PRCTQUES`?